# Как запросить у пользователя разрешение на определение местоположения

Tags: javascript, геолокация

Суть проблемы - почему-то при выполнении моего скрипта браузер не запрашивает разрешение у пользователя на определение местоположения, хотя само местоположение определяется корректно.
пример кода:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
findNear();       
});
```

В хроме в настройках в списке разрешенных/запрещенных сайтов моего нет. Можно все-таки принудительно каким-то способом заставить показаться запрос?

PS мне не нужно определить доступность данных, мне нужно именно вызвать окно запроса, т.к. у меня оно не показывается

Comment: вроде как это будет работать только на `https`

Answer (score 0):

```js
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
     function(position)
     {
      console.log("Доступ разрешён.");
      //действия с полученными данными
     },
     function(error)
     {
      // если ошибка (можно проверить код ошибки)
      if(error.PERMISSION_DENIED)
      {
       console.log("В доступе отказано!");
      }
    });
```

**Читайте также:**

- Документация: [Использование геолокации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation)
- [Местоположение пользователя](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/user-location/?hl=ru)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! К сожалению,это не то, что мне нужно. В данном примере я могу отследить есть ли доступ, но не могу вызвать окно запроса разрешения. На других сайтах это окно вызывается а у меня доступ сразу определяется.

Comment: @Eugenes, это именно то, что вам нужно! Ибо такого, чего хотите вы не существует, насколько мне известно. Вы только представьте себе страницу, которая насилует пользователя и выпытывает у него эти данные снова и снова, несмотря на то, что пользователь это запретил.

Comment: Bharata, Вы невнимательно читаете вопрос. Я же написал
>>В хроме в настройках в списке разрешенных/запрещенных сайтов моего нет
если пользователь запретит сайт, он окажется в списке запрещенных. если разрешит - в списке разрешенных. Сайта нет ни там ни там

Comment: @Eugenes, я ещё раз продумал ваш вопрос и понял, что ваш код, который запрашивает местоположение размещён в iframe, а это для iframe запрещено по умолчанию. Именно поэтому у вас это в настройках не отображается, т.к. туда пишутся адреса главных окон. Попытайтесь добавить это разрешение так: <iframe src="https://example.com" allow="geolocation"></iframe>.

Comment: @Eugenes, если же и это не сработает, то лучше всего будет, если вы посредством **[Window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)** пошлёте из iframe сообщение для главного окна, а главное окно при получении такого сообщения будет уже запрашивать местоположение. Если вас мой ответ удовлетворил, то поставьте галочку рядом с ответом слева, пожалуйста.